# what is this little black plus mark on script icon?

Tags: unity-game-engine, inspector

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LI3vT.png)

what is that black plus mark on script icon?
after that little mark is shown up the script doesn't work
but same script attached other gameobject works well
and also don't have that mark on script icon

Comment: It means this script is not present on prefab asset.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The plus on top of the scripts would then indicate that there are files in the scene that are ready to be uploaded to the shared server.

Comment: Isn't it that it's not applied to the prefab asset?